# SlidesJS Source - Overriding defaults with specified options

Tags: jquery, slidesjs

[SlidesJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/) is a jQuery content-slider plugin. I am trying to understand the source. I am relatively new to Javascript and jQuery. However, what I am interested in, is this line in the source code:

```
$.fn.slides = function( option ) {
   // override defaults with specified option
   option = $.extend( {}, $.fn.slides.option, option );
      ...
}
```

I understand by the comments that the author intends to merge two arrays, one containing the default values for `option` and the other is the `option` argument passed through calling the function. However, don't they both refer to the same variable: the argument of the function `slides(option)`?

It seems to work anyway.
What's the magic here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `option` argument is an `Object` that contains corresponding setting values for the plugin. `$.fn.slides.option` contains the default settings for the plugin. So when you pass your custom settings (via the `option` parameter), these two objects are merged and your custom values overwrites the defaults.

The `jQuery.extend` method is the key here. It merges the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

```
option = $.extend( 
              {}, // the target new Object which represents the final merged options
              $.fn.slides.option, // Object with default option values
              option // Object with custom option values (the passed argument)
         );
```

See [**documentation here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: I do understand the `$.extend` method. But default options aren't defined anywhere in the code (if it is, I can't find it)

EDIT: I got it, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> However, don't they both refer to the same variable: the argument of
>   the function slides(option)?

The answer is no, `$.fn.slides.option` is a property of the `$.fn.slides` function, whereas `option` is a function parameter/argument of the `$.fn.slides` function.

The function parameter or *argument* is like a local variable only accessible within the function block, unlike properties of functions that share the same scope as the function itself.